# how to make efi script that launches linux kernel?

Tags: uefi

I'm trying to set up a simple efistub on my fresh arch linux system with simple editing of kernel parameters.

Current process: there is an EFI boot option created by efistub that launches /EFI/arch/script.nsh on EFI partition, which contains string `\EFI\arch\vmlinuz-linux` (without params yet, just a test). It doesn't work (skips and loads from next medium), but it works if I launch that script from the UEFI shell from arch install medium.

What am I doing wrong? If I'm moving in the wrong way, what's the most close and/or elegant solution?